# How to extract f from given data data in mathematica

Tags: matrix, mathematica-online, webmathematica

How to get all f separately in a table in mathematica

T={{{a=0.3,b=2,c=5,f=5}},{{a=0.6,b=0.2,c=1.5,f=0.33}},{{a=0.13,b=2,c=7,f=11}}}

Comment: is what contained in T a string?  Because it makes no sense otherwise. If you type `{{f = 11}, {f = 8}}` what do you think `f` value will be at the end?

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. The introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from.

Comment: What is your goal in setting up this calculation? Could you please describe it in words?

Comment: If you are looking to get the final value of each inner list (in this case, {5, 0.33,11}) you can get it by indexing using Part, or directly with T[[All, 1, 4]].

Comment: Depending on your situation you may want to change all `a=0.3` to `a->0.3` for example. That is, replace `Set` with `Rule`.

Answer (score 0):

Arguments to functions are evaluated before fed to the function. Therefore, in your example, e.g.: "a=0.5" would be evaluated and replaced by "0.5". Therefore, "T" would contain:

```
{{{0.3, 2, 5, 5}}, {{0.6, 0.2, 1.5, 0.33}}, {{0.13, 2, 7, 11}}}
```

To get all the values assigned to "f" you would write:

```
T[[All, 1, 3]]
(* {5, 1.5, 7} *)
```

From the above you may see that your definition of "T" does not make sense. On the other hand, if "T" is a string, as Nasser suggest, you would write (note: I am using lower case names because the system uses upper case):

```
t = "{{{a=0.3,b=2,c=5,f=5}},{{a=0.6,b=0.2,c=1.5,f=0.33}},{{a=0.13,b=2,\
c=7,f=11}}}";
StringCases[t, "f=" ~~ x : NumberString -> x] 

(* {"5", "0.33", "11"} *)
```

This are all strings. However, if you want values, you write:

```
StringCases[t, "f=" ~~ x : NumberString :> ToExpression[x]]
```